# FTPSClient to store document

Tags: java, ftp-client

I am having an issue putting a document on a FTPS server using the Apache IO [FTPSClient](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPSClient.html).  I am able to connect to the server.  My status is fine( 211 is returned).  If I ask for a list of directories I am getting null.

```
// context is the SSL context
FTPSClient client = new FTPSClient(context);
InputStream stream = null;
    try {
        // fetching a document from a URL.  returning the input stream.
        // The stream is not null
        ContentDocDO docDo = soapClient.fetchDocument(docURL, contextOpt);
        stream = docDo.getStream();


        client.connect("someftpserver.com");
        client.enterLocalPassiveMode();
        client.login("someuser", "somepassword");
        client.changeWorkingDirectory("/RIM/test");
        System.out.println("client status: "+client.getStatus());
        // Changing the name of the document to be stored
        String fileName = docNameMap.get(name) + docDo.getContentType();

        client.storeFile(fileName,stream);
        stream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
     finally {
         try{
            if(stream != null){
                stream.close();
            }
         client.disconnect();
     }catch(IOException e){

         e.printStackTrace();
     }
}
```

I am not seeing any errors.  I can connect to the server via FileZilla.  It uses explicit FTP over TLS.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking too narrowly at the status.  I added the following line:

```
client.addProtocolCommandListener(new PrintCommandListener(
                            new PrintWriter(System.out)));
```

Which allowed me to see that the PROT had not been set.  Then adding:

```
client.execPROT("P");
```

Allowed all to go through.